# How do I set mirrors in /etc/apt/sources.list with a Debian preseed file?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, preseed

I'm building a custom ISO image of Debian 10 stable ("buster") using [preseeding](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed), and my custom `preseed.cfg` file works perfectly except for one thing: I'd like it to configure `/etc/apt/sources.list` with my chosen repositories so that I don't have to do it manually every time I install a new system.

The goal is an `/etc/apt/sources.list` that looks like this (https is a necessity here):

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb https://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb https://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

My `preseed.cfg` file looks like this:

```
#### Contents of the preconfiguration file (for buster)
### Localization
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

# Keyboard selection.
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
# d-i keyboard-configuration/toggle select No toggling

### Network configuration
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostname
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain
d-i netcfg/hostname string vienna1-preseed

d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

### Mirror settings
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string http.us.debian.org
d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian
d-i mirror/http/proxy string

### Account setup
d-i passwd/root-login boolean false

# To create a normal user account.
d-i passwd/user-fullname string theusername
d-i passwd/username string theusername
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password $6$qVk198UWGPxpW$tzMYxQyiOrI4ClDJdDGALsyYq1j1IbXWbpem3JevFT9Krqdmt4wKdvtiY8ry3PRh277V6GHzSKP3zSI7jt04Y/

### Clock and time zone setup
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string US/Eastern

d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

### Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true


# https://serverfault.com/a/622818
d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-first boolean false
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-next boolean false
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-failed boolean false

### Base system installation
# Configure APT to not install recommended packages by default. Use of this
# option can result in an incomplete system and should only be used by very
# experienced users.
#d-i base-installer/install-recommends boolean false

### Apt setup
# You can choose to install non-free and contrib software.
d-i apt-setup/non-free boolean true
d-i apt-setup/contrib boolean true

### Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select full-upgrade
popularity-contest popularity-contest/participate boolean false

### Boot loader installation
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string default

d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
d-i debian-installer/exit/poweroff boolean true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `d-i preseed/late_command string` commands in `preseed.cfg` do what you want. I added a custom `sources.list` file to the iso and then copy that over after the installation completes. Add these commands at the end of your `preseed.cfg`.

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
cp sources.list /target/etc/apt/sources.list; \
in-target apt-get update; \
in-target apt-get install -y git;
```

The last two commands demonstrate updating the list of packages and installing a package that isn't included on the cd (git).

Here's how I built the iso image with the new `preseed.cfg` and the new `sources.list`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Install dependencies
# sudo apt install isolinux syslinux-utils xorriso

cd ~
mkdir iso
xorriso -osirrox on -indev debian-10.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso -extract / iso/

chmod +w -R iso/install.amd/
gunzip iso/install.amd/initrd.gz
echo preseed.cfg | cpio -H newc -o -A -F iso/install.amd/initrd
echo sources.list | cpio -H newc -o -A -F iso/install.amd/initrd
gzip iso/install.amd/initrd
chmod -w -R iso/install.amd/

cd iso/
chmod +w md5sum.txt
md5sum `find -follow -type f` > md5sum.txt
cd ..

xorriso -as mkisofs -o preseed.iso -isohybrid-mbr /usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isohdpfx.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table iso
```

This script assumes that you're working with Debian 10 stable ("buster") amd64, and that `preseed.cfg` and `sources.list` files are in the home directory of whatever system you're using to build the iso.

Answer (score 0):

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    echo "{{source1}}" > /target/etc/apt/sources.txt; \
    echo "{{source2}}" >> /target/etc/apt/sources.txt; \
    echo "{{source3}}" >> /target/etc/apt/sources.txt; \
    in-target mv /etc/apt/sources.txt /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    in-target chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    in-target apt update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y; \
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to [edit] and expand/explain your answer

Comment: You should probably delete the ```; \``` from the last line.